# Find the nodes and coefficients of Gauss-Lobatto Quadrature with $n=4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Gauss-Lobatto quadrature is defined as:

$\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx\approx w_1 f(-1)+w_n f(1) + \Sigma_{k=2}^{n-1}w_k f(x_k)$

($2\leq n\in\Bbb{N}$)

Where the nodes $x_k$ and the coefficients $w_k$ are choosen such that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$ is **exact** if $f$ is a **polynomial** of degree at **most** $2n-3$.

Find the $x_k$'s and $w_k$'s for $n=4$.

---

I've tried to solve it by substituting the polynomials $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5$ for $f$, but I got stucked when I've tried to solve the resulting **non-linear** system of 6 equations in 6 variables.

If I haven't made any mistake, the resulting **non-linear** system is:

$$\begin{cases}
w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4=2 \\ 
-w_1+x_2w_2+x_3w_3+w_4=0 \\ 
w_1+x_2^2w_2+x_3^2w_3+w_4=\frac{2}{3} \\
-w_1+x_2^3w_2+x_3^3w_3+w_4=0 \\
w_1+x_2^4w_2+x_3^4w_3+w_4=\frac{2}{5} \\
-w_1+x_2^5w_2+x_3^5w_3+w_4=0
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks for any hint or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$
J[f(x)] \equiv \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx.
$$
in invariant under change $f(x) \to f(-x)$:
$$J[f(x)] = J[f(-x)]. \tag1 $$
Let's restrict the quardature to share this property
$$
Q[f(x)] \equiv w_1 f(-1) + w_n f(1) + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} w_k f(x_k)\\
Q[f(x)] = Q[f(-x)]
$$
Expanding the $Q[f(-x)]$ we obtain
$$
w_n f(-1) + w_1 f(-1) + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} w_k f(-x_k) = Q[f(-x)] = 
Q[f(x)] = w_1 f(-1) + w_n f(1) + \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} w_k f(x_k)
$$
and the condition is guaranteed if
$$
w_1 = w_n\\
w_k = w_{n+1-k}\\
x_k = -x_{n+1-k}.
$$
Next, every function $f(x)$ can be decomposed into symmetric and asymmetric parts
$$
f(x) = f_s(x) + f_a(x)\\
f_s(x) \equiv \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} = f_s(-x)\\
f_a(x) \equiv \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2} = -f_a(-x).
$$
Note that
$$
J[f(x)] = J[f_s(x) + f_a(x)] = J[f_s(x)] + J[f_a(x)] \overset{(1)}{=}
J[f_s(-x)] + J[f_a(-x)] = J[f_s(x)] - J[f_a(x)]\\
J[f_a(x)] = 0\\
J[f(x)] = J[f_s(x)].
$$
Just the same is true for $Q[f]$:
$$
Q[f_a(x)] = 0\\
Q[f(x)] = Q[f_s(x)].
$$
So it really sufficies to require $Q[f(x)] = J[f(x)]$ only for symmetric functions $f(x) = f(-x)$, so you can exclude odd powers of $x$ (you can still left them, though, but that would be equations $0 = 0$):
$$
w_1 + w_2 = 1\\
w_1 + w_2 x_2^2 = \frac{1}{3}\\
w_1 + w_2 x_2^4 = \frac{1}{5}
$$
Subtracting adjacent equations one gets
$$
w_2 (1 - x_2^2) = \frac{2}{3}\\
w_2 x_2^2(1 -x_2^2) = \frac{2}{15}
$$
and dividing gives
$$
x_2 = \pm \sqrt\frac{1}{5}.
$$
You can pick up any sign, since $x_3 = -x_2$, thus chaging sign only rearranges the points in quadrature. The weights are
$$
w_2 = \frac{5}{6}, \quad w_1 = \frac{1}{6}
$$
and the whole rule is
$$
Q[f(x)] = \frac{f(1) + f(-1)}{6} + \frac{5}{6}\left(f\left(\sqrt\frac{1}{5}\right)+f\left(-\sqrt\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't noticed that an answer has been posted and I will study your explanation in depth a little latter.